# Pass @Published properties from view controllers to SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

Suppose you have a legacy view controller that I'd like to use with SwiftUI. The view controller has one @Published property that contains it current state:

```swift
class LegacyViewController: UIViewController {
    enum State {
        case opened
        case closed
        case halfOpened
    }
    
    @Published var state: State
    
    override init(nibName nibNameOrNil: String?, bundle nibBundleOrNil: Bundle?) {
        self.state = .closed
        super.init(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
    }
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // state is changed after some time
    }
}
```

Ideally, I'd like to use it with SwiftUI like this:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var state: LegacyViewController.State
    
    var body: some View {
        VCWrapper(state: $state).overlay (
            Text("\(state)")
        )
    }
}
```

which would mean that I need to implement `UIViewControllerRepresentable` protocol:

```swift
struct VCWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var state: LegacyViewController.State
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> LegacyViewController {
        let vc = LegacyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)
        /// where to perform the actual binding?
        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: LegacyViewController, context: Context) {
        
    }
}
```

However, I'm having trouble figuring out where to do the actual binding from `state` property of the `LegacyViewController` to the `state` property exposed by `VCWrapper`. If `LegacyViewController` exposed a delegate, I could implement the binding through the `Coordinator` object, but I'm not so sure how to do this considering that I don't use a delegate object?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is possible solution - use `Combine`. Tested with Xcode 12 / iOS 14.

```
import Combine

struct VCWrapper: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    @Binding var state: LegacyViewController.State
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> LegacyViewController {
        let vc = LegacyViewController(nibName: nil, bundle: nil)

        // subscribe to controller state publisher and update bound
        // external state
        context.coordinator.cancelable = vc.$state
            .sink {
               DispatchQueue.main.async {
                  _state.wrappedValue = $0
               }
            }

        return vc
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: LegacyViewController, context: Context) {
    }
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        Coordinator()
    }
    
    class Coordinator {
        var cancelable: AnyCancellable?
    }
}
```

Comment: That approach works, but I get `Modifying state during view update, this will cause undefined behavior.` warning that I've seen with few other approaches as well.

Comment: Well, I don't know when/where do you modify state in view controller, but try as updated - it is verified fix for such warning.